# Add files to /var/www/

Tags: permissions, directory, root

I just installed `lamp-server^` and wanted to try it I created a php file but I was not able to move it to `/var/www` because owner of that folder is root I managed it using terminal (I logged in as root). But I dont want to do it everytime. Is there any other way to do it? I dont want to use terminal every time I want to try to access that folder.

Comment: Im  not just interested in that specific folder. Any folders with root owner.  I want to know what to do If it happens again with another folder.

Comment: same applies, just use different group. what other folder are you thinking of?

Comment: @L0RDQB you just use `sudo cp foo bar` to copy `foo` to `bar`.

Comment: @L0RDQB any root folders (other than `/var/www`) you should use sudo cp to copy. The permissions of them shouldn't be changed (/var/www is an exception).

Comment: is there any other way like giving root access to my current user ?

Comment: I created a symlink to a folder on my desktop for easy access!

Comment: @L0RDQB yes I have a symlink too to a folder called Website for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it is done in LAMP, but a pure Apache setup has a user group called `www-data` with write permission into `/var/www`.

To achieve the same result, follow these steps:

1. Create the group `www-data`, if not already existent (check with `grep www-data /etc/group`):

   groupadd www-data
2. Transfer group ownership of `/var/www` to `www-data`, if not already done:

   ```
   sudo chgrp www-data /var/www
   ```
3. Add your user to the `www-data` group:

   ```
   sudo usermod -a -G www-data <username>
   ```
4. Fix permissions, if necessary (give full permission to group members):

   ```
   sudo chmod g+rwx /var/www
   ```

Now you can access the directory without sudoing.